# PHP shell / psysh: starting directory?

Tags: psysh

How to change the directory `psysh` is starting from? It seems to be starting from `/var/www/html` because any file I try to import is referenced from that path... I'd like to start the shell in my app directory.

```
Psy Shell v0.10.4 (PHP 7.3.23 — cli) by Justin Hileman

>>> require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
PHP Fatal error:  Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' in Psy Shell code on line 1
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change the directory in the config file of psysh:

`chdir('/YOUR_FOLDER/');` in `psysh.config.php`

Comment: If someone wants to know where they should put the config, go through this: https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/wiki/Configuration#-configuration